# React hangman game: clicked state not managed correctly producing unexpected behavior

Tags: reactjs

[image]

Hello I have Letters.js which generates AvailableLetter for a-z.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AvailableLetter from './AvailableLetter/AvailableLetter';
import classes from './Letters.module.css';

const Letters = (props) => {
    const [allLetters]=useState(
        ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    );

    const playHandler = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        console.log(solution);

        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            console.log('incorrect');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('correct');
            return true;
        }
    }

    const availableLetters = [ ...allLetters ].map(
        (alphabet,i) => {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter setSolved={props.setSolved} play={()=>playHandler(alphabet)} correct={()=>props.correct(alphabet)} incorrect={()=>props.incorrect(alphabet)} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={alphabet} />
            );
        }
    );



    return (    
        <div className={classes.Letters}>
            <p>Solution: {props.solution}</p>
            <div className={classes.AvailableLetters}>
                {availableLetters}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Letters;
```

I have AvailableLetter.js here and I want it to be unclickable after first time clicked.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';
import Ax from '../../hoc/Ax';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {
    // const [show,setShow]=useState(true);
    // const [clicked, setClicked]=useState(false);
    // const [outcome,setOutcome]=useState(false);
    const [clicked,setClicked]=useState(false);

    // if (show)
    // {
    //     setClicked(true);
    // }

    // const play = (alphabet) => {
    //     const solution = props.solution.split('');
    //     if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
    //     {
    //         return false;
    //     }
    //     else
    //     {
    //         return true;
    //     }
    // }

    const setStuff = () => {
        // setShow(true);
        setClicked(false);
        props.setSolved();
    };
    useEffect( setStuff,[clicked] );

    // useEffect( ()=>setShow(true),[show] );
    // useEffect( ()=>props.setSolved(),[show] );

    if (clicked)         // STRANGELY THIS PART WORKS!!!
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            props.correct();
            // alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect();
            // alert('wrong');
        }
    }

    const attachedClasses = [classes.AvailableLetter];
    const disableLetter = () => {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Disabled);
        setClicked(true);
    };

    // const letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;

    let letter=null;
    if (!clicked)
    {
        letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }
    else if(clicked)    // CODE NEVER GETS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        letter = <span className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <Ax>
            {letter}
        </Ax>
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

The CSS file for it is AvailableLetter.module.css:

```
.AvailableLetter
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.AvailableLetter.Disabled
{
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

It seems my logic inside AvailableLetter is correct, but it never reaches the else if (clicked) part and letters remain always clickable.

Inside AvailableLetter.js: If I use button instead:

```
<button disable={clicked} onClick={()=>setClicked(true)}>props.alphabet</button>
```

Strangely disable doesn't work even when setClicked(true).

But if I do

```
<button disable>props.alphabet</button>
```

Now it disables.

I appreciate your help!

Update:
Removing setClicked(false) from setStuff() gets error:

```
Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your combination of effects and hooks have created a feedback loop.

This button:

```
<span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>
```

calls this function:

```
    const disableLetter = () => {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Disabled);
        setClicked(true);
    };
```

which sets `clicked` to `true`. Once that happens, this effect runs:

```
    const setStuff = () => {
        // setShow(true);
        setClicked(false);
        props.setSolved();
    };
    useEffect( setStuff,[clicked] );
```

which immediately makes `clicked == false` again. Also worth noting that `setStuff` gets called a second time because `clicked` changed values, triggering the effect again. What is `setStuff` supposed to do in this context? Remove the call to `setClicked(false)` in that function and `clicked` should remain as `true`.

I'd highly recommend cleaning up your code so it's easier to follow. Logic like this:

```
if (!clicked) {
  // not clicked
} else if (clicked) {
  // clicked 
}
```

could easily be described like this:

```
if (clicked) {
  // clicked
} else {
  // not clicked
}
```

By doing this, you'll save yourself a lot of headaches when debugging problems like the one you're having.

## Maximum Update Depth Error

Based on your stack trace and code in the question/pastebin, you have *another* loop caused by this part:

```
    if (clicked)
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            props.correct();
            // alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect(); // <- this is your trigger
            // alert('wrong');
        }
    }
```

You should move this code into your `setStuff` function so it's called only once by the effect.

I'd also suggest re-thinking your structure here, so you (and others) can follow what you're doing better. Stack traces will help you with any further errors you get so you can follow the source of more loops you might encounter.

Comment: Removing setClicked(false) from setStuff() gets error: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

Comment: props.setSolved() checks if puzzle has been solved.

Comment: @logan What happens when you turn off the effect entirely? It's possible that you have another bug with `setSolved` itself.

Comment: setSolved worked on my previous version. when effect is removed I get: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Comment: Something's not working now, so you'll have to humour me. If removing `setSolved` from the effect or removing the effect itself fixes the Maximum update depth error, then you'll need to share the contents of your `setSolved` function.

Comment: here's Game.js source which has setSolvedHandler. https://pastebin.com/vU1e48sV

Comment: @logan I can't help you further - you need to fix several problems with your code. StackOverflow is meant for specific problems and/or errors, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem. Since we keep playing whac-a-mole with your code, it would be better to start over or refine your components so it's easier to figure out your exact solution.