# React question: Error: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: reactjs, state, lifecycle, effect

[image]

Hello I have Letters.js which generates AvailableLetter for a-z.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import AvailableLetter from './AvailableLetter/AvailableLetter';
import classes from './Letters.module.css';

const Letters = (props) => {
    const [allLetters]=useState(
        ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
    );

    const playHandler = (alphabet) => {
        const solution = props.solution.split('');
        console.log(solution);

        if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
        {
            console.log('incorrect');
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            console.log('correct');
            return true;
        }
    }

    const availableLetters = [ ...allLetters ].map(
        (alphabet,i) => {
            return (
                <AvailableLetter setSolved={props.setSolved} play={()=>playHandler(alphabet)} correct={()=>props.correct(alphabet)} incorrect={()=>props.incorrect(alphabet)} solution={props.solution} key={i} alphabet={alphabet} />
            );
        }
    );



    return (    
        <div className={classes.Letters}>
            <p>Solution: {props.solution}</p>
            <div className={classes.AvailableLetters}>
                {availableLetters}
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Letters;
```

I have AvailableLetter.js here and I want it to be unclickable after first time clicked.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';
import Ax from '../../hoc/Ax';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {
    // const [show,setShow]=useState(true);
    // const [clicked, setClicked]=useState(false);
    // const [outcome,setOutcome]=useState(false);
    const [clicked,setClicked]=useState(false);

    // if (show)
    // {
    //     setClicked(true);
    // }

    // const play = (alphabet) => {
    //     const solution = props.solution.split('');
    //     if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
    //     {
    //         return false;
    //     }
    //     else
    //     {
    //         return true;
    //     }
    // }

    const setStuff = () => {
        // setShow(true);
        setClicked(false);
        props.setSolved();
    };
    useEffect( setStuff,[clicked] );

    // useEffect( ()=>setShow(true),[show] );
    // useEffect( ()=>props.setSolved(),[show] );

    if (clicked)         // STRANGELY THIS PART WORKS!!!
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            props.correct();
            // alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect();
            // alert('wrong');
        }
    }

    const attachedClasses = [classes.AvailableLetter];
    const disableLetter = () => {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Disabled);
        setClicked(true);
    };

    // const letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;

    let letter=null;
    if (!clicked)
    {
        letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }
    else if(clicked)    // CODE NEVER GETS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
    {
        letter = <span className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <Ax>
            {letter}
        </Ax>
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

The CSS file for it is AvailableLetter.module.css:

```
.AvailableLetter
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 3px;
}

.AvailableLetter.Disabled
{
    pointer-events: none;
    background: #aaa;
}
```

It seems my logic inside AvailableLetter is correct, but it never reaches the else if (clicked) part and letters remain always clickable.

Inside AvailableLetter.js: If I use button instead:

```
<button disable={clicked} onClick={()=>setClicked(true)}>props.alphabet</button>
```

Strangely disable doesn't work even when setClicked(true).

But if I do

```
<button disable>props.alphabet</button>
```

Now it disables.

Removing setClicked(false) from setStuff() gets error:

> Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.

I appreciate your help!

Update:
I've been trying things with extra state called rendered. I have been unsuccessful but making progress.

Updated AvailableLetter.js:

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import classes from './AvailableLetter.module.css';
import Ax from '../../hoc/Ax';

const AvailableLetter = (props) => {
    // const [show,setShow]=useState(true);
    // const [clicked, setClicked]=useState(false);
    // const [outcome,setOutcome]=useState(false);
    const [clicked,setClicked]=useState(false);

    // if unclickable span is rendered set to true.
    const [rendered,setRendered]=useState(false);

    // if (show)
    // {
    //     setClicked(true);
    // }

    // const play = (alphabet) => {
    //     const solution = props.solution.split('');
    //     if (solution.indexOf(alphabet)<0)
    //     {
    //         return false;
    //     }
    //     else
    //     {
    //         return true;
    //     }
    // }

    const setStuff = () => {
        // setShow(true);
        rendered&&setClicked(false);     // CHANGED THIS!!!!!!
        props.setSolved();
    };
    useEffect( setStuff,[clicked,rendered] );

    // useEffect( ()=>setShow(true),[show] );
    // useEffect( ()=>props.setSolved(),[show] );

    if (clicked)         // STRANGELY THIS PART WORKS!!!
    {
        if (props.play())
        {
            props.correct();
            // alert('correct');
        }
        else
        {
            props.incorrect();
            // alert('wrong');
        }
    }

    const attachedClasses = [classes.AvailableLetter];
    const disableLetter = () => {
        attachedClasses.push(classes.Disabled);
        setClicked(true);
    };

    // const letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;

    let letter=null;
    if (!clicked)
    {
        letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }
    else if(clicked&&setRendered(true))    // CAUSES INFINITE LOOP
    {
        letter = <span className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
    }

    return (
        <Ax>
            {letter}
        </Ax>
    );
}

export default AvailableLetter;
```

Thus far, the modified version causes infinite loop!

I've also tried

```
else if(clicked&&!rendered?setRendered(true):null)    // CODE NEVER GETS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
{
   letter = <span className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
}
```

But this time letter remains always clickable and is not greyed out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React hangman game: clicked state not managed correctly producing unexpected behavior](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249405/react-hangman-game-clicked-state-not-managed-correctly-producing-unexpected-beh)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the trace of the code. I'll explain why you get both outcomes

```
letter = <span onClick={disableLetter} className={attachedClasses.join(' ')} >{props.alphabet}</span>;
```

The onClick calls disableLetter setting `setClicked(true)`. React re-renders when a state is set which runs the code

```
const setStuff = () => {
    // setShow(true);
    setClicked(false);
    props.setSolved();
};
```

Setting `setClicked(false)` triggering react to reload again. This code is before

```
 else if(clicked)    // CODE NEVER GETS HERE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
```

Which is why this never gets called. `setStuff()` will always set `setClicked(false)` after each render and it renders each time `setClicked(true)` is called

Removing `setClicked(false)` puts you in an infinite loop. props.setSolve() causes a re-render as well. Every time your app renders it calls props.setSolve()

Comment: so i need to render letter BEFORE setClicked(false).

Comment: that would fix  "CODE NEVER GETS HERE...". But you may still have an unwanted outcome. 

Even if setClicked(false) is after it you are still setting the click to false right after it was set to true (which defeats the purpose of using setClicked and doesn't disable your button)

Comment: In general, this code can be hard to debug. I would suggest simplifying the code and adding print statements to try and debug. 

The problem here is really the unwanted re-rendering of your code which is either causing code to not run or infinite loops. If you can figure out what is causing a re-render then you can more easily debug future errors.